# MobileMe Connection - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, webdav, mobileme

I need to send a file to MobileMe via Cocoa. I stumbled across a .Mac framework from Apple but it hasn't been updated in years, so I don't want to use it due to possible compatibility problems it may cause. I think that the MobileMe.framework is private, so I don't think I can use it.

What kind of alternatives are there available for me so that I can upload the file to MobileMe? I've also been looking into WebDav frameworks (since MobileMe is WebDav based), but I didn't find anything useful either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`FMWebDavRequest`](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/davtest/) or [ConnectionKit](http://opensource.utr-software.com/connection/).